# Open link from webview in chrome for android

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am trying to open a link in chrome from a webview on android. Is it possible to do this with the URI rather than using an intent.

For example doing something like "chrome://www.google.com"

I have been looking around on here and other places on the internet seeing things like googlechrome:// and googlechrome://navigate?url= as well, but I cannot seem to find anything that works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to force it to open in chrome, however, I was able to force it open in the android browser by replacing "https" with "browser." I still do not know if it is possible to force it out of the webview and open it with chrome, but this solution works for my purposes.